# Reprojection Scanning Technique

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

While reprojection a raster using 'Raster - Reprojection - Warp' in QGIS I can choose one of the following scanning techniques: Nah, Bilinear, Cubic, Cubic Spline, Lanczos. What does Nah mean and which one is recommended?

Comment: Haha, that seems like a bug. Should be "Near" for Nearest Neighbor. Can you confirm it says that and it was just a typo?

Comment: Then it might just be a uncommon translation as I'm using a german version. It's really 'Nah' and I don't see how this could mean Nearest Neighbor (in german: Nächster-Nachbar) but I guess you have to be right.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somewhere there is an answer to this on GIS SE with GIS specific recommendations. But even if, [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26385/difference-between-none-linear-cubic-and-sinclanczos3-interpolation-in-image) and the link in the comments to [Comparison of OpenCV Interpolation Algorithms](http://tanbakuchi.com/posts/comparison-of-openv-interpolation-algorithms/) seem like the perfect compendium.